# Memory errors despite plenty of headroom (Ubuntu VPS)

Tags: linux, memory, outofmemoryerror

I'm getting all sorts of memory-related errors from python and php, plus segmentation faults - yet the output of `free -m` constantly shows plenty of spare memory - i.e.

```
greg@greg-brown:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1024        520        503          0          0        163
-/+ buffers/cache:        356        667
Swap:          512          0        512
```

Does this mean a hardware issue? How would I go about debugging this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get out of memory errors if you attempt to allocate a single block larger than is available in a single contiguous block, even if there is plenty of memory available in many smaller blocks.  This happens especially on 32-bit systems when the virtual address space becomes fragmented, which becomes more and more likely as the usage approaches 2GB and the longer it's been in use.  Google "memory fragmentation" for more information.

Comment: Thanks, that's a possibility. Rebooting the server doesn't seem to help though and I'd have thought it would with fragmentation?

Comment: Yes. A clean slate should result in everything being contiguous. It would require a full reboot, though, not one of those newfangled restarts that really is just a hibernate and resume. If it fails after that, a hardware issue seems likely. If it is a server, you can check the IPMI for memory errors. If not, the BIOS might tell you something, but you should probably run an exhaustive memory test. Note that it is still possible that the code does allocations during startup in a specific way that causes the issue, but that seems unlikely.